# How remove an element from a list inside of a dictionary?

Tags: python

```
days = {'10/02':['Eat Pie', 'Eat Pizza'], '12/03': 'Drink Wine'}

def delete_event(k, x, y):
  if type(days[k]) == list:
    for k in days:
  days[k] = days[k][x:y]
  elif type(days[k]) != list:
    del days[k]
  print('That event has been deleted. Here is the new list: ')
  print(days)
```

I have a dictionary that contains dates and events. A date can save more than one event in a form of a list. How would I go about deleting a specific event from the list? But if there isn't more than one event just delete the whole thing (the key and value). Is it possible to do it? I need to have a function with an algorithm. Any time i put in a value for x and y it gets rid of the values in all keys instead of just the specific key i want.
https://repl.it/@footballmania1/Mock
That is the link to my current project I need help fixing the delete function.

Comment: So if the value is a list of events and you only want to delete one event from each one, how do you choose which one to delete? And by "delete the whole thing" when there is only one event do you mean remove the date's key and value from the dictionary, or just the value?

Comment: What does that do (or not do) that isn't what you expect?

Comment: `del days[key]`, i.e. `del days['12/03']`

Comment: dodging downvotes: @ninjaguy-558 
would something like this work? https://repl.it/@downshift/RepentantQuaintService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def remove_schedule(days, date, to_remove=None):
    if to_remove is None:
        del days[date]
    else:
        days[date].remove(to_remove)

days = {'10/02': ['Eat Pie', 'Eat Pizza'], '12/03': ['Drink Wine']}
remove_schedule(days, '10/02', 'Eat Pizza')
print(days)
```

Here is the codes.

the result of this codes above would be

`{'10/02': ['Eat Pie'], '12/03': ['Drink Wine']}`

if you want to remove the whole dictionary key, you can just do

`remove_schedule(days, '10/02')`

And this will remove the key and value

Comment: Why did you put an =None next to to_remove\

Comment: @Ninjaguy558 It means if I give only 2 parameters, `to_remove` sets to None as a default. This way, you can remove the set of key & values at once without giving which one to remove.

Comment: @Ninjaguy558 For example, if I do `remove_schedule(days, '10/02')`, it sets `to_remove` as None and results in removing the all values of `10/02`. And if I do `remove_schedule(days,'10/02', 'Eat Pie')`, then I specified that `to_remove` is `'Eat Pie'` which will result in removing only `'Eat Pie'`.

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped.

Comment: @Ninjaguy558 Also note that even if you do `remove_schedule(days, '12/03', 'Drink Wine')` , `'12/03'` key remains as `'12/03' : []`. If you don't want to leave an empty list, then you could add `if not days[date]: del days[date]` at the end of the `else:` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
def deleter(my_dict, date, event):
    try:
        my_dict[date].remove(event)
        if not my_dict[date]:
            my_dict.pop(date)
    except:
        del my_dict[date]
```

It accepts your dict, your date, and your event

eg.

```
days = {'10/02':['Eat Pie', 'Eat Pizza'], '12/03': 'Drink Wine'}
deleter(days, '12/03', 'Drink Wine')
deleter(days, '10/02', 'Eat Pie')

print(days)
>> {'10/02': ['Eat Pizza']}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
days = {'10/02':['Eat Pie', 'Eat Pizza'], '12/03': ['Drink Wine']}
for i in days.values():
    del i[0]
print (days)
```

Comment: so if i were to put that in a function how would it look